# Can Cisco Umbrella be Used Along with Google Classroom?

Tags: cisco, google-cloud-platform

We are creating an Information Assurance and Security Plan for a public school. The Plan will include [Google Classroom](https://edu.google.com/intl/en_uk/products/classroom/) because the school doesn’t have an online learning platform. The problem is our teacher is requiring security software to use so we have searched about Cisco Umbrella. Is it possible to use Cisco Umbrella with Google Classroom?

Note: I am a student and I don’t have much background about Information Security sorry.

Comment: I assume this is a homework assignment and that you are not creating a plan to be implemented for an actual school?

Comment: I think you need to read about what Umbrella does and what Classroom is. They are not dependent on each other nor do they block each other. This is a little like asking, "can I own a goldfish if I already own a car?" You can certainly use either, both, or neither.

Comment: @schroeder Nope this is not a homework assignment. We really creating a IAS plan. About your second reply- Yes thats what we were thinking. Obviously Google Classroom is a very secure site and it doesn’t need third party programs to protect it. But the catch is “our teacher is requiring a security software to use”. I am just probably gonna say to her what you said to me that “It is useless because google classroom and umbrella are not dependent on each other”. Thanks for the response :D

Comment: Is the plan to secure Google or to secure the staff and students of the school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for on-site security you might prefer to look at:
https://pi-hole.net/

Cisco Umbrella controls DNS requests, it blocks bad ones and allows 'good' ones. Google Classroom is web-based and you will be able to set filters to allow access in the Cisco Umbrella dashboard. It is probably allowed by default. Note for students' mobile devices you will need to ensure they support the Umbrella client and/or use the school's network inc. DNS forwarder / Umbrella public IPs (previously OpenDNS) - this might be difficult to enforce, pi-hole could be a smarter move for on-site security. Meanwhile, ensure you are using Single-sign-on as much as possible: https://ed.link/community/how-to-implement-sso-for-google-classroom/

Comment: *"this might be difficult to enforce"* - why? If you can set up the clients to use pi-hole as DNS you can also make clients to use Umbrella as DNS. Also, while Umbrella traditionally was simply DNS based security it can do more than that today, i.e. it can also do TLS intercepting web proxy and more. And, even with DNS the quality depends on the actual deny lists employed and I very much doubt that pi-hole here has the same quality regarding malware sites as Umbrella. Not to disregard pi-hole, but it simply isn't the main focus.

Comment: Yes I am referring to on site security. I am accepting your answer because you have stated a usage of google classroom and cisco umbrella. But more research is required for me to understand the topic. Thanks a lot. But i agree with @steffen Ullrich tho I have read further about cisco umbrella and it is not only for control DNS request. It can also block DDOS attacks and etc. Thanks again :D

Comment: @GeromeTahud An important point to realise is Cisco Umbrella does not block DDOS attacks against you, its designed as a mitigation for handling compromised devices already on your network participting in a DDOS attack. Nothing on your network can protect against DDOS attacks directed at your network.

Comment: "this might be difficult to enforce" - why? By alerting users to having to install the umbrella client on their mobile devices it could discourage adoption or it could be subverted. A bigger challenge is that of DNS over HTTPS and how Umbrella could manage blocking that.